# Do E-Stop switches/buttons normally operate relay switches?

Tags: safety

I have a high-power system requiring an e-stop button, but a browse on Farnell suggests that no buttons are really designed to do the job of circuit breaking directly, based on their current/voltage ratings. I would have thought a safety system would want to be a simple as possible and not require a relay to function as well, but the search seems to suggest otherwise.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: In modern industrial installations it's common to use safety relays or even full blown safety PLC's (for example PILZ) to handle the installations safeties. Which include emergency stop buttons but also other things like door locks or light curtains.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the NC contact of an E-stop button served to de-energise a motor contactor / clutch / brake or a pneumatic / hydraulic solenoid valve, in order to shut down a machine during an emergency.

Accidents, as a result of failure to shut down caused by a faulty E-stop button, were prevented by multiple E-stop button NC contacts wired in series.

Other safety systems were then progressively introduced e.g. safety guard interlocks, two-hand push button operation, light curtains etc.

The key component used in the functioning and integration of these systems is the relay. Fail-safe dual redundant relays are in turn monitored by a third relay to prevent a machine start, should one of them have failed.

The ultimate solution would be a safety PLC which can handle not only the functions of a standard PLC but also the safety functions that have been integrated into it.